# modify parent of specified li element JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm new to using 'this', but if I am understanding this correctly, I can only use this inside a function defined within another.

In this case I am selecting a li item based on its a href and I need to add a class if it meets the criteria. I feel like I'm close but missing something small, 'url[1]' is from a split.

```
if ($('#Navbar li a:contains(' + url[1] + ')').attr('href')) {
    function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I am looping through my Li objects based and comparing the href's to look for a match. Thanks to everyone for helping me through this. I have a much better understanding of `this` now:

```
     $('#Navbar li a').each(function () {
     if ($(this).attr('href')==url[1]) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
         }
     });
```

Comment: Add your markup to the question. Otherwise it is hard to tell you the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('#Navbar li a').each(function () {
 if ($(this).attr('href')==url[1]) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     }
 });
```

The loop was the trick. Thanks: @roasted @brenjt @Maverick

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the context in which it is being used. So `this` is referring to the anonymous function you created. A better solution to your problem would be:

```
var nav_item = $('Navbar li a:contains(' + url[1] + ')');

if (nav_item.attr('href')) {
    nav_item.parent().addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: So, just so I understand...This code snippet creates an object(`nav_item`) only if the li a contains the matching href. Then, if there is in an object that has been created we are modifying its parent's class to recieve 'active' class

Comment: Yes correct. But if you are wanting to check more than one `nav_item` then you would need to do an `.each` loop

Comment: That's precisely what I am doing, and arrived at the conclusion immediately before your post. Here is is my current workthrough, but its currently wrong: repost above

Comment: @atlMapper That is exactly how you would want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

$(this) not point to your targeted element (i think without seeing your full html code). Try following code:

```
var $a =$('Navbar li a:contains(' + url[1] + ')');
if ($a.attr('href')) {
        $a.parent().addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple! :)

```
if ($('Navbar li a:contains(' + url[1] + ')').attr('href')) {
    var that=this;
    function () {
        //your condition checking
        $(that).parent().addClass('active');
    }
}
```

UPDATE:: above code is WRONG

You can do it like this as well...

```
$('Navbar li a:contains(' + url[1] + ')').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).attr('href')){
        if(yourCOndition){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this is depending of context. 'If' doesnt create any context rule.

Comment: @roasted So...the `this` will never be created because `if` doesnt create any context rule?

Comment: Mr. @atlMapper : Right... In that case `this` will be the owner of that `if` condition.

Comment: @Maverick, no if conditions are not contexts, and are not referred to by this